# Ruby on Rails Problem PotionStore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to install the PotionStore on my Mac OS X 10.6 server with Ruby on Rails 3 installed. Upon launching the server on port 3000 and pointing safari to this address, I get this:

> NameError in
>   Store/orderController#index
>
> uninitialized constant
>   ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::PGconn

What does this mean? I'm not too advanced with Ruby on Rails, so this throws me a bit.

Comment: Have you set up your local PostgreSQL server?

Comment: The application is configured to use postgresql: https://github.com/potionfactory/potionstore/blob/master/config/database.yml. It may / may not work with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application is [configured to use PostgreSQ](https://github.com/potionfactory/potionstore/blob/master/config/database.yml)L, as I already stated in the comment. You can change the adapter value here to `mysql` to change it to use MySQL. The README says it works, but it may not.

I feel I need to elaborate further on what this application specifically *is*. It's a Ruby on Rails 2 application and if you've installed Rails 3 and you're trying to use it to boot the application then you're going to run into some headaches. **3 is not backwards compatible with 2.**

You've got three options.

The first is to upgrade the application (which it sounds like you're not familiar with) to Rails 3 and get all the latest and greatest goodies, such as Bundler for example.

The second is to ask the potionfactory guys / girls nicely if they wouldn't mind upgrading it to Rails 3 because "it's a really great application and I want to use it".

The third is to leave it in it's old state and switch to using an older version of Rails (2.1 or "higher" the README states), anything in the 2.1.x - 2.3.x range should work, but for reasons that should be obvious, you should be using the latest 2.3.x release. This would be made much easier by using [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com) and its gemsets functionality.

Comment: There is a fork of PotionStore that is compatible with Rails 3: https://github.com/expandrive/potionstore  Unfortunately I haven't gotten it to completely work.  When attempting to "buy" software using a PayPal sandbox account, I get the error "Unknown action: The action 'show' could not be found for Store::OrderController"